# How to create 3D animation "flip effect" with a canvas element

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Being a bit of a newbie to css/html/js an issue has come up that I was hoping to get help with regarding animation with a canvas element. Using html and css I have been able to create a flip effect (for Spanish/English vocabulary flashcards, English on one side, Spanish on the other) but the visual is a very basic colored rectangle. I prefer to use canvas to draw the image (i.e. lined flashcard). The flashcard has been created in canvas but I'm stuck on how to apply animation methods (css transition and transform properties) to the canvas element. Below is the code for the flashcard created with canvas.Thank you for any help you can send this way.

```
/*FLASHCARD DRAWING*/

<head>
<title>flashcard_1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
style type="text/css">

#myCanvas {
margin: 20px;
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
float: left;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="230"
style="border: 1px solid black;"
</canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

ctx.moveTo(0,35);
ctx.lineTo(500,35);
ctx.strokeStyle='#3399ff';
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,60);
ctx.lineTo(500,60);
ctx.lineWidth = .5;
ctx.strokeStyle='#ff3333';
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(0,85);
ctx.lineTo(500,85);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(0,110);
ctx.lineTo(500,110);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(0,135);
ctx.lineTo(500,135);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(0,160);
ctx.lineTo(500,160);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(0,185);
ctx.lineTo(500,185);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.moveTo(0,210);
ctx.lineTo(500,210);
ctx.stroke();

</script>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: If you already have it working with HTML/CSS it might be better to store the flashcard as an image and apply it as background for the rectangle.

Comment: Would this effect help you? check this site and click on flip button [site](http://www.paranormalpa.net/store.php)

Comment: #Chevi - thank you for the suggestion. I've got it working now.